# Why can I compile against libclang-3.5.so and not against libclang.so?

Tags: compiling, gcc, symbolic-link, shared-library, dynamic-linking

I am trying to compile a C source file, that needs to be linked against a dynamic library I installed through `apt-get` (libclang.so).

`apt-get` installed the clang shared libraries in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Here are the relevant files :

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.4.so -> libclang-3.4.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.4.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.5.so -> libclang-3.5.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.5.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so.1 -> libclang-3.5.so.1
```

The loader seems to know about libclang :

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep clang
        libclang.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so.1
```

In fact, my problem is reproducible no matter what the content of the source file I'm trying to compile is, as long as it contains valid code. So, I used this source file:

```
$ cat a.c 
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling against clang fails:

```
$ gcc a.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lclang
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclang
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But compiling against clang-3.5 (or clang-3.4) succeeds:

```
$ gcc a.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lclang-3.5
$
```

I really need to be able to link using `-lclang` and not `-lclang-3.5`, because actually I cannot control how this compiler option is generated in my real-world problem. What can I do to make `-lclang` work ?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and GCC 4.8.2.